# Solution codewars to car Mileage problem, running out of ideas?

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, monotone

I am trying to work out a solution to the CodeWars challenge [Catching Car Mileage Numbers](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52c4dd683bfd3b434c000292/train/java):

> Write the function that parses the mileage number input, and returns a 2 if the number is "interesting" (see below), a 1 if an interesting number occurs within the next two miles, or a 0 if the number is not interesting.
>
> Interesting numbers are 3-or-more digit numbers that meet one or more of the following criteria:
>
> - Any digit followed by all zeros: 100, 90000
> - Every digit is the same number: 1111
> - The digits are sequential, incementing<sup>†</sup>: 1234
> - The digits are sequential, decrementing<sup>‡</sup>: 4321
> - The digits are a palindrome: 1221 or 73837
> - The digits match one of the values in the `awesomePhrases` array
>
> <sup>†</sup> *For incrementing sequences, 0 should come after 9, and not before 1, as in 7890.*
> <sup>‡</sup> *For decrementing sequences, 0 should come after 1, and not before 9, as in 3210.*

I can pass all tests in the first batch, but fail to pass the second batch.

Any feedback would be very much appreciated, not only on a possible solution but also to the way I'm thinking about the exercise.

```
public static int isInteresting(int number, int[] awesomePhrases) {
    for (int offSet = 0; offSet <= 2; offSet++) {
        int testNumber = number;
        testNumber += offSet;
        boolean isYellow = testNumber != number;
        int yellowOffset = 0;
        if (isYellow) {
            yellowOffset = 1;
        }
        //check three or more digit number
        boolean greaterThan99 = testNumber > 99;
        int[] numbers = Integer.toString(testNumber).chars().map(c -> c - '0').toArray();
        int zeroCounter = 0;
        int identicalCounter = 0;
        int incrementingCounter = 0;
        int decrementingCounter = 0;
        int palindromeCounter = 0;
        boolean endsInZero = numbers[numbers.length - 1] == 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            //check digit followed by zeros
            if (numbers[i] == 0) {
                zeroCounter++;
            }
            if (i + 1 < numbers.length) {
                //check every digit is the same
                if (numbers[i] == numbers[i + 1]) identicalCounter++;
                //check ascending order
                if (numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] == 1) incrementingCounter++;
                //check descending order
                if (numbers[i] - numbers[i + 1] == 1) decrementingCounter++;
            }
        }        
        if (greaterThan99) {
            //check awesomePhrases
            for (int phrase : awesomePhrases) {
                if (phrase == testNumber) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            }
            //check palindrome
            int reversedIndex = numbers.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (numbers[reversedIndex] == numbers[i]) {
                    palindromeCounter++;
                }
                reversedIndex--;
            }            
            if (zeroCounter == numbers.length - 1) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (identicalCounter == numbers.length - 1) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (incrementingCounter == numbers.length - 1) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (incrementingCounter == numbers.length - 2 && endsInZero) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (decrementingCounter == numbers.length - 1) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (decrementingCounter == numbers.length - 2 && endsInZero) return 2 - yellowOffset;
            if (palindromeCounter == numbers.length) return 2 - yellowOffset;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried pretty much all I know but to no result, all the tests I try pass, would love to know what I'm doing wrong.

[image: 1]

Comment: It's supposed to be a hard question so I'm not mad at the number and breath of the tests it just makes it harder when you don't really know what some of those tests are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in how your code tests for increasing sequences that end in a zero. It is not enough to test that the sequence has n-2 increments and the last digit is a zero, because that will give a false positive on numbers like 6780. It is required that the one-but-last digit is a 9.

A similar issue exist for the *decreasing* sequence logic, however, there you would not need a special test for an ending zero at all. This condition is covered by counting n-1 decrements, where the ending could be a 1 followed by a zero. There is no special case to be handled here.

To fix the first problem, I would suggest you not only check whether the last digit is a zero, but whether the last two digits are 9 and 0, or in other words, that the number modulo 100 is equal to 90.

You could replace this:

```
boolean endsInZero = numbers[numbers.length - 1] == 0;
```

by this:

```
boolean endsInNinety = testNumber % 100 == 90;
```

and then replace:

```
if (incrementingCounter == numbers.length - 2 && endsInZero) return 2 - yellowOffset;
```

by:

```
if (incrementingCounter == numbers.length - 2 && endsInNinety) return 2 - yellowOffset;
```

and finally remove this test:

```
if (decrementingCounter == numbers.length - 2 && endsInZero) return 2 - yellowOffset;
```

This will fix it.

Note that it can be helpful to have your function *print* the input it gets, so that when a test fails, at least you can know for which input there was a problem:

```
System.out.println("input " + number);
```

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely correct !! I haven't fully grasped the logic of your solution yet but I will and now I can sleep in peace ;)